# How to set Grub Password

Tags: grub2, password, security, bootloader

Red Hat Linux has grub-md5-crypt for setting up a grub password. How to do the same in Ubuntu 13.10 ?

Comment: look here for solution already said in ubuntu https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords

Answer (score 1):

check this
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords

grub-md5-crypt was for older versions of grub .
ubuntu 13.10 uses grub2

Comment: This helps a little bit but i can't still get a clear idea of grub2 .